# Is there a good way to optimize p0 in scipy.optimize.curve_fit?

Tags: python, scipy, model, regression, curve-fitting

I am trying to use curve fit to fit some temperature that looks like a sinusoid function added to a linear function. My initial predictions are way off and I believe it is because I need to adjust p0, however I was wondering if there was a good way to get an initial guess for p0 or if its just an endless game of guess and check. Alternatively, if there is a better way to get the regression line please let me know!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not algorithmic. It all depends on the model and data. E.g., if there's a sinusoid, a rough guess for the period (e.g. from the distance between maxima) goes a long way etc

Answer (score 0):

y(x)=a + p x + b sin(w x) + c cos(w x)

with 5 adjustable parameters : w , a , p , b , c .

This is a problem of nonlinear regression. The usual way to solve it involves iterative calculus starting from guessed values of the parameters.

A non conventional method (not iterative, no initial values required) is explained in the paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales.

Theory pp.47-48. Practical application and numerical example pp.49-53 .